# How to send node as body content in email using Rules?

Tags: 7, rules, emails

I wonder if there is a way of inserting the contents of a node into the body of the email when using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the Rules Event that your rules is using ... e.g.:

- If Rules Event is something like "*After updating existing content*", then you'll be able to use token `[node:body]` within (eg) the message body of Rules action "send eMail".
- If Rules Event is (eg) "*After updating an existing user account*" then token `[node:body]` is not available for using it within (eg) the message body of Rules action "send eMail".

Comment: This case is of the second type where the node is not available. Could one perhaps in the conditions check for the existence of a specific node, and thus make it available?

Comment: @Bosse Your new comment here seems like a **new** (additional) question. I'd say "pretty sure yes". Though you'd need to provide more details about that "specific". I suggest you post that as a new question, if you want with a link to your question here and an indication like "followup" question. If you do, maybe you also want to mark "this" answer as accepted (because IMO this answer is an answer to your question here)?